# Test Index and Character

Tags: java

```
char val;
int idx = 1;
do {
    if (PasswordGenerator.matchCharAt (val, idx))
        System.out.println("The Password is " + password);
    idx++;
} while (idx < 127 );
```

I'm suppose to tests if the character parameter matches the character in the password at the specified index.  There may be a lot of things that are wrong with just that because I've been messing with it for 2 hours.

Then I need to append them with stringbuilder together (which I'm not worried about) and display the characters to the screen (I'm also not worried about that).

I have no idea how to loop them to check the ascii letters from 0-127. So I need help trying to figure that out.

[This is the documentation](http://www.technology.heartland.edu/faculty/todds/csci130/assignments/A5_password/doc/index.html) for PasswordGenerator.

I'm trying to get the Password to display random letters within my password (pretty much or at least I think). This is what I did to get the password length...

```
int length=0;
int MaxNumber=100;
StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();

do {
    if (PasswordGenerator.matchLength (length))
        System.out.println("The length of the character is " + length);
    length++;                     // length is randomly picked
} while (length < MaxNumber );   // or <100
```

Comment: what *exactly* are you trying to achieve? and why does it fail?

Comment: it looks like you are never setting/updating the val that you are checking against.

Comment: I think this one's hopeless. That Javadoc says there is a **static** method that matches a character at an index with a "password". What password? Where is that password stored? Why would a static method be used for such a thing? Have you not heard of `String.charAt()` -- or `Object.equals`, for that matter? Good luck with this one, guys. A gem.

Comment: I would guess that what you are supposed to take in the password attempt from the user (or somewhere) and compare that to the password you have saved in PasswordGenerator.

Comment: Can't use those for this assignment. Kinda have to use what the instructor says.

Comment: Overall the length portion of it, when compiled, has a random password length stored, and the length would be (1-100 characters).  Here are the behaviors my instructor left me with..

Comment: ^Sorry, can't reformat any of that.

Comment: @JohnMac you should probably move that into the question body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A char is a primitive type - you can iterate with it just like any number.  for example:

```
for (char c = Character.MIN_VALUE; c < Character.MAX_VALUE; c++) {
  // do stuff
}
```

In your case, you might limit the values to between 0 and 127, according to whatever you've been given, but a char is effectively a numeric type.

Comment: The for loop: for( char c = 'a'; c < 'z'; c++) {} is also valid.

Comment: @ColinD if you know that you'll be between a and z lowercase :) but yes

Comment: Yeah its from 0 to 127, that sounds like a good start for my loop.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to structure your program as a loop nested inside another loop. The outer loop variable is the index of the next character to find. The inner loop then searches for the character that matches the password character at that position. Since you don't know the actual length of the password, you need to terminate the outer loop after you find `n`<sup>th</sup> character *and* `n` matches the length of the password.

Something like this might be what you need:

```
PasswordGenerator password = ...
OUTER:
for (int len = 0; !password.matchLength(len); ) {
    for (char c = 0; c < 128; ++c) {
        if (password.matchCharAt(c, len)) {
            // found the match at index len -- record it
            ++len;
            continue OUTER; // exit the inner loop
    }
    // no match at all found for index len --
    // exit with failure
}
// exit with success
```

Normally I dislike using statement labels, but this seems a natural place to use one. However, you could get rid of it by using an extra flag variable or something.